# why can't I use scanf on visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
int main(void)
{
    double y,k,r;
    int x, o;
    y = x;

    printf("years: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    o = x;
    r = 100.0;
    while (y > 0.1)
    {
        printf(" after %dyears = %lf", x, k);
        y = y * x;
        x = x + o;
        k = r / 2.0;
    }
    printf("1/10 under=%dyears", x);

    return 0;

}
```

i wrote the #define CRT,... why can't I use scanf?
'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

this is what it says....

Comment: You need to place the define directive before the include directive.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define it *before* including any headers that directly or indirectly includes `stdio.h`:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: @caooooos Happy New Year :-)